# Difference Between HTTP request in code vs web browser

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, server

I'm wondering is there any difference between a standard http request from code vs a request sent by submitting a html form. Of course there will be obvious things such as user agent and what not.

I want to send a request to a page and the page will create a session variable. Currently I have a PHP script that is generating a HTTP request (i have tried curl & file_get_contents using stream_context_create) to a page and pulling back the response. This same PHP page also has some javascript that will use ajax to generate the exact same request.

When the PHP creates the request without the JS, the session is created and returned in the response, but when i visit a new page, the session is dead. When I use the ajax on its own the request returns the session data and when i visit other pages the session still exists. NOTE: I also tried to use a html form and post to the url and this also works to keep the session alive.

I cant figure out why this is happening. My only thought is that it could be caused by some discrepancy between the default values for the php request and the ajax request.

Request page content

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = "Works";
var_dump($_SESSION);
```

PHP script content

```
<?php 
session_start();
var_dump($_SESSION);
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

$username = "test";
$password = "test";

$url = "https://website.com/test.php"; 
$postinfo = "username=".$username."&password=".$password;
// $ch = curl_init($url);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postinfo);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,  2);
// $result = curl_exec($ch);
// curl_close($ch);
$data = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $password);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
var_dump($result);

?>

<?php echo time();?>
<form action="<?php echo $url;?>" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username"><br>
    <input type="text" name="password"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"   integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo $url;?>",
        data: { username: '<?php echo $username;?>', password: '<?php echo $password;?>' },
        success: function (content) {
            alert(content);
            console.log("Request Response = " + content);
        },
        fail: function (message) {
            alert("Failure - " + message);
            editmemberform.dialog('close');
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

When i run the script, the response i get from the php request is

```
string(49) "array(1) { ["message"]=> string(5) "Works" } "
```

To me this suggests that the session was created as the session data is being dumped out. The ajax request then makes the request and the response is the exact same. This is what gets written to the console.

```
Request Response = array(1) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(5) "Works"
}
```

I cant understand why 2 identical requests are acting like this. I have also tried to perform the post request from an ASP.NET script and im having the same issue. There must be something different about the request a browser generates vs the code request.

Note: I have tried this using http and https. I never get any errors. The response is always correct.

The php script is running on an IIS8 server using PHP 5.4

Comment: main difference would be session cookies which browser manages internally but you would need to manage yourself with cURL

Comment: You're not saving the session cookie, so EVERY request your script makes will be a new/different session.

Comment: how do i define the default session cookie? I want to be able to create login session data so a user can be logged into multiple sites at once. The code request will need to make the session within the standard browser based session, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a lot will be different actually.

Since the page you're requesting through code is most likely built to be browsed by humans in a web browser, it will have various technologies - cookies and javascript mainly.

Your PHP script won't be able to handle the JavaScript (ie: say after 5 seconds you land on the page in the browser, a `<div></div>` is written to the DOM with a value fetched from a remote server - your PHP script won't get this), unless you use a headless browser - such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).

> When the PHP creates the request without the JS, the session is created and returned in the response, but when i visit a new page, **the session is dead.**

Your PHP code won't store cookies for the next visit to that webpage (at its current setup). [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) supports a cookiejar [option](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) (`CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION`, `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR`) to send cookies from previous requests.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
```

See [this comment on the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#61395) for more information.

Comment: is there any way to make it use the default session cookie? I want to deploy this code as a way to log users into multiple sites using different languages. This way they can log in once on the php site and will also be logged into the asp site and any other sites needed. To do this i need to make the session inside the default cookie

Comment: Are you in control of the other sites? If so, look into [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) and [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). If you want to send your own cookies, use the `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, [...]);` option.

Comment: I am in control of them, but this is more of a nice to have feature. i thought it would be a quick case of making a http request to a file and it would build the session. If i cannot access this cookie from a remote script i will have to save this for another day. The 2 links provided will be very valuable for me in the future though. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> When the PHP creates the request without the JS, the session is created and returned in the response, but when i visit a new page, the session is dead.

When PHP creates the request, the session isn't persisted to your browser.

You could try using some .js to set a `PHPSESSID` cookie on your browser with the session ID as the one that got created via your PHP script to see for yourself! (Though this is probably a security issue and might not work perfectly.)

Comment: i dont want to use .js for this though. i just used it to demonstrate that it was working. i need to pass sensitive data around and im not happy having to put this data in the body of the html in order for javascript to use it. I need to exclusively create the session using code and no client side logic

Comment: I only mean to say that you could use js as a means to see what the server-generated session looks like in your browser. Purely for testing/dev/educational purposes.